# How to setup grub.conf for a newly compiled kernel

Tags: linux, grub

I installed MPLS on linux 2.6.15 using the instructions here:
http://www.sj.ifsc.edu.br/~msobral/RCO2/docs/mpls-linux/1-3-installation.html
Everything worked but I don't know how to set up grub.conf so that it runs the new kernel. Here is the current grub.conf:

```
default=1
timrout=10
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
title MPLS
      root (hd0,0)
      kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.15 ro root=LABEL=/1 hda=ide-scsi hdc=ide-scsi
      initrd /initrd-2.6.15.img
title CentOS-3 (2.4.21-50.EL)
      root (hd0,0)
      kernel /vmlinuz-2.4.21-50.EL ro root=LABEL=/ hda=ide-scsi hdc=ide-scsi
      initrd /initrd-2.4.21-50.EL.img
```

Here is the error I get if I boot MPLS:

```
insmod: QM_MODULES:

ERROR: /bin/insmod exited abnormally!
Creating block devices
VFS: Cannot open root device "LABEL=/" or unknown-block(0,0)
Please append a correct "root" boot option
Kernel panic - not syncing : VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Any ideas?